# Science fiction story where a boy chooses a knife instead of other weapons

Tags: story-identification, books

What is the name of the book/story where a boy goes to a planet and is offered the choice of  many weapons but chooses a knife.

I read it when I was in secondary school in the seventies.

Comment: Can you remember anything useful, character names, why he was given weapons, what he ultimately needed to fight, anything else that he said or did?

Comment: Your question made me think of John Locke from Lost. He wasn't offered other weapons, but he did choose a knife among a set of other objects presented to him by Richard Alpert.

Comment: This question reminds me of [Hunters of the Red Moon](http://www.amazon.com/Hunters-Moon-Marion-Zimmer-Bradley/dp/1938185064), although I know that it isn't the answer.  However, in looking it up I just discovered there's a sequel I'll have to go look for.

Answer (score 30):

It's [*Tunnel In the Sky*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_in_the_Sky) by Robert A Heinlein. The hero has a conversation with his (much more experienced) sister near the beginning of the book where she advises him to take a knife and not a gun on his advanced survival test (which is on a different planet).

To quote from the linked Wikipedia article:

> Rod, acting on his older sister's advice, takes hunting knives and
>   basic survival gear rather than high-tech weaponry, on the grounds
>   that the latter could make him over-confident.

Comment: Absolutely. And during the story, many of the people with the high tech weapons did not fare very well overall. I thought this was one of Heinlein's best young adult novels.

Comment: Thank you so much . I'm sure that is the book. Trying to think of it has been troubling me for days. I recognise the writer now. Thank you Kenny and Bobson.

Comment: [The Heinlein Juveniles](https://www.goodreads.com/series/127324-heinlein-juveniles) are the best!

Answer (score -4):

Would also fit "Dune"; compare the fight between Paul Atreides (Kyle McLachlan) and Feyd-Rautha Harkonnen (Sting) in the 1984 film adaptation of the book series of the same name.

Comment: He's not offered the choice of a more advanced weapon. The fight is kris-knife against kris-knife...

Comment: Plus this answer is clearly referring to the movie, which A) is not a book, and B) 1984, the year it was made, is after the seventies, when the OP read the book/story.